# Thread stucks at serversocket.accept() in android

Tags: java, android, tcpserver, qtcpsocket, tcpsocket

I want to create communication android app using tcp server-client. I am using android phone as server and linux pc as client, I have created application  on linux which works as client.When I Try to create server, it stuck at serversocket.accept(). So client is not able to connect server. I am using following code for server creation

```
class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    int dsport = 48618
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            server_socket = new ServerSocket(dsport);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {
                socket = server_socket.accept();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And I am using qt creator on client side

```
void run()
 {
 Qstring iplist;
 QList<QHostAddress> ipadd = QNetworkInterface::allAddress();
 socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
 connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(newConnection)));
 socket->connectToHost(ipadd.at(0),48618);
 }

void newConnection()
{
qDebug()<<"socket connected";
}
```

here ipadd.at(0) gives me local host address. Is there any issue with port I am using? if yes then how to get reliable port for server creation.
How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: You android phone has probably some firewall settings for incoming connections. But I think you need to use firebase push messages instead of running a server on your phone.

Comment: And your phone needs to be in the same network, without NAT between it.

Comment: @PeterBruins how to use firebase push msgs? can you send me some links or tutorials? and I am creating hotspot on android phone, client linux is connected to that hotspot. so it is connected to same network

Comment: If your devices are in the same network, then it should work. Do you have all the necessary permissions? I don't think there is an issue with the port you are using. Then `new ServerSocket(dsport)` would have failed already

Comment: Yeah I have added all permissions.

Comment: I think there is a problem at your client side. If you also post client code than maybe we can point out the issue.

Comment: I m using qt creator for client application on linux, client side code is as follows.

Comment: `Qstring iplist;
QList<QHostAddress> ipadd = QNetworkInterface::allAddress();
socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(newConnection)));
socket->connectToHost(ipadd.at(0),48618);` here ipadd.at(0) gives me local host address

Comment: I have also added client side code in question.

Comment: can anyone tell me what am I suppose to do to resolve this? or is there any other method to achieve the client server connection